# Using :not with :nth-child in the same selector?

Tags: css

I'm trying to target some elements that are dynamiccally generated by slick slider.

I have 4 divs...

```
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
```

The plugin then adds additonal divs so it renders like...

```
<div class="slick-slider slick-cloned"></div>
<div class="slick-slider slick-active"></div>
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
<div class="slick-slider"></div>
<div class="slick-slider slick-cloned"></div>
```

I want to target the original elements, so to do that I'm trying to say **not** `slick-cloned` and then use the `nth` selector to target accordingly. The below doesn't work however, has anybody an idea why?

**CSS**

```
.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned):nth-child(1)
```

Comment: No it doesn't @dgknca - i tried that beforehand

Comment: If that “no it doesn’t” was in response to the duplicate (the “does this answer your question” phrasing SO has decided to go with, is terrible IMHO) - yes it does, in so far that it explains that the combination of the `nth-` selectors with other selectors in such a way is not possible.

Comment: I would probably go and add an additional class to all slides that are _not_ `.slick-cloned` via JavaScript, after the slider has initialized (it has an event for that) - and add a counter in that class name, so that it’ll be `original-1`, `original-2` etc. afterwards. Then you got something you can specifically target via your CSS. (Or you add those classes before, maybe even on the server side already - then you still get clones of those as well, but then `.original-1:not(.slick-cloned)` would work, resp. maybe a different class name than `original-` then, `slide-1` etc.)